# Using parvaiew/vtk to analyze a tree like structure

Tags: json, hdf5, vtk, paraview

I have a Newton optimizer and I am exporting some data in the form of a HDF5. The HDF5 file contains the results of the optimization process, which are triangle meshes, so I am loading them in paraview.

In addition, the HDF5 file contains information about how the optimization went, so I have a json like structure with information about the number of newton iterations, the newton error. For each Newton iteration I store the number of iterations of the inner linear solver and the number of iterations of a line search process and so on. Basically, I have a tree like structure where each node in the tree may contain different amounts of attributes.

Since I am already using paraview to read the geometric data, I was looking for an appropiate VTK structure to store the rest of the data in the HDF5 file. I have looked into VTKTree, but apparently, all the nodes contains the same amount of attributes.

Is there any VTK structure which I can use to parse this type of information?

Answer (score 0):

Hierarchical storage of unrelated meshes (i.e. meshes with differents attributes) can be done through [vtkMultiBlockDataSet](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkMultiBlockDataSet.html#details)
or [vtkPartionedDataSetCollection](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkPartitionedDataSetCollection.html#details).

Also note that if you have miscellaneous data associated to a mesh, you can stock them in the [vtkFieldData](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkFieldData.html#details) of the `vtkDataObject` containg your mesh.

Comment: The data is not associated with a mesh. When the optimizations finishes, it has compute the position of several vertices (which are stored as meshes), but I also store information about the procces, for example, how many iterations the optimizer did. This data is not related to a mesh, but to a vtkMultiBlockDataSet, and I am not sure if it can be stored there

Comment: Those kind of metadata should be stored as `FieldData`, see this [example](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Cxx/PolyData/FieldData/)